# Only reads the first item in the json file

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm having trouble reading a .JSON file and creating a DTO object ... when I read only I get the first item from the json file, everything else is null.
Why does it happen?
The way my variable is written in the class should be the same as it is in json?

Class Dto

```
public class AlunoTestDto {

private String table;
private String rows;
private String AlunoID;
private String Nome;
private String RM;
private String RG;
private String usuario;
private String senha;
private String cursoAluno;
private String urlFoto;
private String email;
private String rgEscolar;
private String cpf;


public String getTable() {
    return table;
}

public void setTable(String table) {
    this.table = table;
}

public String getRow() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRow(String rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}//others
```

Method that reads json

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    AlunoTestDto alunoTestDto=null;
    alunoTestDto = objectMapper.readValue(new File("alunos2.json"), AlunoTestDto.class);
```

Json File

```
        "table": "bws_aluno",
"rows":
[
    {
        "AlunoID": 1,
        "Nome": "Mayk Reserv",
        "RM": "4545454545",
        "RG": "7535214-7",
        "Usuario": null,
        "Senha": null,
        "CursoAluno": null,
        "UrlFoto": null,
        "Email": "",
        "RGEscolar": null,
        "CPF": null     
    },
    {
        "AlunoID": 2,
        "Nome": "Philip Lombard",
        "RM": "26585651",
        "RG": "123456980",
        "Usuario": null,
        "Senha": null,
        "CursoAluno": null,
        "UrlFoto": null,
        "Email": "",
        "RGEscolar": null,
        "CPF": null

    },
    {
        "AlunoID": 3,
        "Nome": "Bilbo Bolseiro",
        "RM": "75898774",
        "RG": "36522-8",
        "Usuario": null,
        "Senha": null,
        "CursoAluno": null,
        "UrlFoto": null,
        "Email": "",
        "RGEscolar": null,
        "CPF": null         
    }
]
```

}

[null object image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVY0r.png)

Comment: I think if you remove the FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES configuration and debug the exception instead, that will give you the idea why the json is not getting parsed correctly.

Comment: I think your json consists of rows, and the person is inside the row.

feed your code with just the rows of json, instead of the table and rows coming separately.

Comment: but if I do this (I remove the table and the rows from my dto) it points to the table's missing error, do I have to change the .JSON file?

Comment: @lisaandrewsmarkitks I really don't know how the Jackson object mapper works like, but according to me, I would create two DTO's, one would have the table and and arraylist of student dto (which is the second dto) named as rows.

the second dto would be student with attributes from AlunoID to cpf. Then I guess if Jackson mapper supports it, it would create one object of AlunoTestDto with a table name and an array list inside it, inside the row arraylist, you would have all the students data.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested (great idea) but unfortunately it does not recognize...
Unrecognized field "AlunoID" (class com.package.bws.model.Aluno), not marked as ignorable (11 known properties: "urlFoto", "senha", "alunoID", "cpf", "rm", "email", "usuario", "cursoAluno", "rg", "nome", "rgEscolar"])

Comment: Perfect ...Farhan Qasim... the problem is that my variables were private in the model: /
thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"rows":` in JSON is Array or List of objects (let say `class Row`), 
but your DTO has `row` as String...

so, there is nothing in JSON file to fill beyond `"table"` element

Comment: so my dto class will only have to have a list of students, is that it? can you give an example of how my dto should be?

Comment: Yes.you are right. Sorry I'm on phone and cannot give you example, but all you need another class for what is in array (Student?) And then `rows` property as `List<Student>` or Array `Student[]` if you'd like